# JavaScript - Insert & Remove a element in object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a object.

```
var dl_items;
```

After a loop for inputing data:

```
dl_items[code] = itemObject;
```

I have a array:

```
dl_items : {
            "code_A" : { "index" : 1, "status" : 2, "name" : A_data},
            "code_B" : { "index" : 2, "status" : 0, "name" : B_data},
            "code_C" : { "index" : 3, "status" : 1, "name" : C_data},
            "code_D" : { "index" : 4, "status" : 2, "name" : D_data},
            "code_E" : { "index" : 5, "status" : 4, "name" : E_data}
           }
```

Now I want to remove "dl_items[code_D]" and insert it into after "code_A" (index 2) for result like :

```
 dl_items : {
            "code_A" : { "index" : 1, "status" : 2, "name" : A_data},
            "code_D" : { "index" : 4, "status" : 2, "name" : D_data},
            "code_B" : { "index" : 2, "status" : 0, "name" : B_data},
            "code_C" : { "index" : 3, "status" : 1, "name" : C_data},                
            "code_E" : { "index" : 5, "status" : 4, "name" : E_data}
            }
```

I try to use "delete" after using a loop to find index of code_D:

```
delete dl_items[code_D];
```

and it successful removed but how can i insert code_D into his new index ?

Edit : Thanks all everyone to help me understand more about array.

Comment: basically you show an object with objects. properties in objects have actually no order. you could use an array for ordered items.

Comment: That's neither [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation) nor an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). `dl_items` is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Please correct your array

Comment: as @NinaScholz said, you can use an array, that will hold objects, that way you can easily just rewrite the index you want `array[3] = { status: 2, name: d_data}`, in javascript array is an object.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a way of encoding data in strings.

Comment: In JS, do not think in terms of "removing" or "inserting" elements into arrays. Instead, think in terms of creating a new array, with some elements added or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since object doesn't have an order, you need to convert your current implementation into array:

```
var dl_items = [];
```

When you need to add an item to the array:

```
dl_items.push({ code: code, item: itemObject });
```

Now, the similar data as array from your question is:

```
dl_items: [
            { code :"code_A", item: { index: 1, status: 2, name: "A_data" } },
            { code :"code_B", item: { index: 2, status: 0, name: "B_data" } },
            { code :"code_C", item: { index: 3, status: 1, name: "C_data" } },
            { code :"code_D", item: { index: 4, status: 2, name: "D_data" } },
            { code :"code_E", item: { index: 5, status: 3, name: "E_data" } },
          ]
```

In order to move the entry with code_D after the entry with code_A, use the following:

```
var codeDEntry = dl_items[3];
dl_items = dl_items
    .filter(function(entry) {
        return entry !== codeDEntry;
    })
    .splice(1, 0, codeDEntry);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can i ask why you used `unshift` ? In w3school, it said that `unshift` using to add a item to beginning of array.
And i think your new array will be : D, A, B, C , E ?
Please correct me if i was wrong :D

Comment: Sorry, you completely right. I didn't read the question properly. I Fixed my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now i will refactor the structure of my code a lot :D

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a temp var like this :

```
tempItem = dl_items.code_D;
dl_items.code_D = dl_items.code_B;
dl_items.code_B = tempItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is an object, not an array. Therefore, there is no concept of an index here.
You can map your object keys into an array as follows:

```
 let array = Object.keys(dl_items);
```

You can then reorder their positions.